# synchronizing executeSql in Safari (WebKit) Web Sql database

Tags: javascript, sql, html, web-storage

WebKit (Safari 4+ is my focus) has a feature called Web SQL.
Web SQL is specified in  [the W3C draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/).
Currently only the asynchronous flavor is supported.

I have a situation where I want to synchronize a few different operations - writing to database (using CREATE TABLE query and then a loop through INSERT queries) and then reading from the database. How do I do this? I googled and read a lot of tutorials, but did not find any explanation of that.

If I can't find answer to this, I shall try the Worker feature and if unsuccessful I plan to store the data in [webstorage (localstorage)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a possible solution for this in my blog. Don't know if that would fit your problem, but have a look.
http://wander-mind.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-synchronize-html5-websql-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that nbody answers this. My current undertanding is that storing a block in localstorage is the best

Comment: someone has. A bit late to the party perhaps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You chain the operations through success callbacks. That way you can be sure of the order of operations. See the example code available in [this article](http://kinderas.blogspot.no/2011/02/html-5-offline-data-storage.html?codekitCB=397134785.496139).

You can use the callbacks available for the transaction object or the individual queries, `tx.executeSql(sql, [], callback, errorCallback)`.

```
var sql_createTables = "CREATE .....",
  sql_inserts= "INSERT .....";

function errorHandler(tx, error) { 
  //do error handling
}

db.transaction(
 function(tx){
  tx.executeSql(sql_createTables,[], function(tx, result){
     //The table was created
    tx.executeSql(sql_inserts,[], function(tx, result){
       // Inserts completed
    });
  },
  errorHandler);
 }, function(error) { alert("Oh, noes! The whole transaction failed!"); },
 function() { alert("Yeah, baby! We did it."); });
```

WebWorker has nothing to do with this, and will not help you in any way, as a `WebWorker` has no access to the DOM, of which `localStorage` and `WebSql` are parts.